# Is $\{\emptyset,a,\epsilon\}$ an algebraic structure with respect to $+$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, group-theory

Let $R = \{\emptyset,a,\epsilon\}$ (the elements here are regular expressions) and let $+$ be the *or* operation, which can be applied over the regular expressions of $R$. Is $(R,+)$ some kind of an algebraic structure, such as a subgroup, a monoid, or a group?

I was told that it is monoid and that $(a+\epsilon)=a$, and so $R$ is closed under $+$. But if $R$ is a set of regular expressions then $(a+\epsilon)$ is itself a regular expression and it does not belong to $R$, so $R$ should not be closed under the $+$ operation. So is $R$ an algebraic structure or not? Please correct me if I am understanding it wrong.

Comment: *I was told.* Can you provide a reference?

Comment: Your earlier title mentioned posets. A poset consists of a set together with a binary *relation* satisfying some axioms.

Comment: The interpretation of the regular expression $a+\epsilon$ is a language of cardinal 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all algebraic structures I am aware of, the set $R$ should be closed under the operation $+$. While you haven't provided a clear definition of $+$, there is no reasonable definition of $+$ which makes $R$ closed under $+$, since $a + \epsilon$ (interpreted either as a regular expression or as a language) does not belong to $R$.

If we add $a + \epsilon$ to $R$ and interpret $+$ as union of *languages*, then $R$ does become closed under $+$, and we can ask whether it satisfies the axioms of any interesting algebraic structure. For any such structure, we just need to check whether all axioms are satisfied. This is something that you can do on your own.